# for-each in XSLT issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to XSLT and trying to for out for-each loop so that each node would match another node from different root. I have following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <class> 
        <students>
            <student> 
                <firstname>Dinkar</firstname> 
                <teacher_id>1</teacher_id>
            </student> 
            <student > 
                <firstname>Vaneet</firstname> 
                <teacher_id>2</teacher_id>
            </student> 
            <student> 
                <firstname>Jasvir</firstname> 
                <teacher_id>3</teacher_id>
            </student> 
        </students>
        <teachers>
            <teacher>
                <tfirstname>Dima</tfirstname>
                <teacher_id>1</teacher_id>
            </teacher>
            <teacher>
                <tfirstname>Vova</tfirstname>
                <teacher_id>2</teacher_id>
            </teacher>
            <teacher>
                <tfirstname>Denis</tfirstname>
                <teacher_id>3</teacher_id>
            </teacher>
        </teachers>
    </class>
```

I need to get following XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<G2>
   <Student_Name>Dinkar</Student_Name>
   <TName>Dima</TName>
</G2>
<G2>
   <Student_Name>Vaneet</Student_Name>
   <TName>Vova</TName>
</G2>
<G2>
   <Student_Name>Jasvir</Student_Name>
   <TName>Denis</TName>
</G2>
```

Meaning that each student gets teacher's name according to matching id.
However I get all teacher names instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<G2>
   <Student_Name>Dinkar</Student_Name>
   <TName>Dima Vova Denis</TName>
</G2>
<G2>
   <Student_Name>Vaneet</Student_Name>
   <TName>Dima Vova Denis</TName>
</G2>
<G2>
   <Student_Name>Jasvir</Student_Name>
   <TName>Dima Vova Denis</TName>
</G2>
```

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="class/students/student">
            <G2>
            <Student_Name><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></Student_Name>
            <xsl:if test="/class/teachers/teacher/teacher_id=teacher_id">
                <TName><xsl:value-of select="/class/teachers/teacher/tfirstname"/></TName>
            </xsl:if>
            </G2>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can you assist please.

Comment: I am pretty sure you do not need the "xsl:if". That seems to always be true. Just select the teacher node by id and insert its tfirstname value.

Comment: it is simplified version of more complex XML. Could you please provide the full cod eon how it can be achieved, as I am honestly lost.

Comment: Not really sure but should be `select="/class/teachers/teacher[teacher_id=./teacher_id]/tfirstname"` Or at least something similar.

Comment: Oh, and if you made your template match="class/students/student" you wouldn't even need the for-each afaik.

Comment: Tried that one before, but the out was the same. I assume it has to do something with the absolute path, but I am not sure , as not experienced enough:(

Comment: @beginner777 If you want the `<TName>` to be conditional, then define a variable - so that you only need to perform the lookup once.

Comment: I don't know if it matters to you, but I believe your output xml lacks a root element. Maybe it's due to the simplification ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/class/teachers/teacher/tfirstname"/>
```

selects **all** teachers first names, with no regard to your current context. You want to change it to a conditional one:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/class/teachers/teacher[teacher_id=current()/teacher_id]/tfirstname"/>
```

---

Even better, define a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key)** as:

```
<xsl:key name="teacher-by-id" match="teacher" use="teacher_id" />
```

then use it as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('teacher-by-id', teacher_id)/tfirstname"/>
```

to perform the lookup. This is especially convenient if you want to output the name only when the lookup is successful:

```
<xsl:variable name="teacher" select="key('teacher-by-id', teacher_id)" />
<xsl:if test="$teacher">            
    <TName>
        <xsl:value-of select="$teacher/tfirstname"/>
    </TName>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: @Fildor That's an unrelated problem. Let OP post a new question, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Guy's can you please also recommend some good and comprehensive XSLT/xPath tutorials? Tried to search ones on the web, but seem to be too basic((((

Answer (score 0):

Making the minimal changes to your code, you could try this (keep the teacher_id in a variable so then you can find the corresponding element).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
                version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//student">
            <xsl:variable name="teacher_id">
                <xsl:value-of select="teacher_id"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <G2>
                <Student_Name><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></Student_Name>
                <TName><xsl:value-of select="//teacher[teacher_id=$teacher_id]/tfirstname"/></TName>
            </G2>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```